# When i try to reshape, it gives me an error saying "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, reshape

Actually, i am trying to convert Matlab code to python and when i try to reshape, it throws me a TypeError saying "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple".

**Matlab**

```
[file,path] = uigetfile('*.dwr');
fid = fopen(strcat(path,'/',file));
m5 = (fread(fid, '*uint8'));
m5=double(m5);
fclose(fid);
m6=m5(12514:end);
no_bin_ele=m5(12039:2:12218)+256*m5(12040:2:12218);
s1=size(m6);
s2=((no_bin_ele(1)*7+4)*360)*1;
n1=m6(1:s2);
j1=reshape(n1(1:end,1),no_bin_ele(1)*7+4,360*1);
```

**Python**

```
import numpy as np
with open('aa.dwr', 'rb') as fp:
m5 = np.fromstring(fp.read(), dtype='uint8')
m5 = m5.astype(float)
m5 = m5.tolist()
m6 = m5[12514:]
no_bin_ele = m5[12039:12218:2]+256*m5[12040:12218:2]
s1 = len(m6)
s2=((no_bin_ele[1]*7+4)*360)*1
s2 =int(s2)
n1=m6[1:s2]
j1 = np.reshape(n1[1: ,1], no_bin_ele[1]*7+4, 360*1)
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ppp.py", line 26, in 
>       j1 = np.reshape(n1[1: ,1], no_bin_ele[1]*7+4, 360*1)
>   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Just saying, you know, that element 1 in matlab is element 0 in python, right? In general Matlab starts counting at 1, so all your indices are probably wrong

Comment: Will you please paste the output of the following "print(no_bin_ele.shape, no_bin_ele[1])"?

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about that. Thank you. So, what should I do now? @LeoE

Comment: print(no_bin_ele.shape, no_bin_ele[1])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' @Amit

Comment: probably the following will work ..    j1 = np.reshape(n1[1: ,1], (no_bin_ele[0]*7+4, 360*1))

Comment: not working @Amit

Comment: It's not the reshape, it's the indexing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking this MATLAB line:

```
no_bin_ele=m5(12039:2:12218)+256*m5(12040:2:12218);
```

In Octave I verify that

```
12039:2:12218
```

produces 90 values, 12039 to 12217.

```
12040:2:12218
```

also produces 90, 12040 to 12218

So the line is taking summing successive pairs, `m5[i]+256*m5[i+1]`  Since they were loaded as `uint8`, this makes, I think a `uint16` value.

But in `numpy`:

```
In [467]: np.arange(12039,12218,2).shape                                        
Out[467]: (90,)
In [468]: np.arange(12040,12218,2).shape                                        
Out[468]: (89,)
```

The end point handling is different.  The 2nd slice end point should be 12219.

That accounts for the broadcasting error when `m5` is an array (which it should be):

```
no_bin_ele = m5[12039:12218:2]+256*m5[12040:12218:2]
```

Converting `m5` `tolist()` does not help.  For a list `*` means replicate, and `+` means join.  For an array those are multiply and add.  totally different.

```
In [475]: alist = list(range(0,10))                                             
In [476]: alist                                                                 
Out[476]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
In [477]: alist[1:6:2] + 4*alist[2:6:2]                                         
Out[477]: [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]
```

The rest of the code sort-of-runs with the list because indexing and slicing is the same - up until the `n1[1: ,1]` expression.  This is only valid for a numpy array.

Actually, there are other indexing issues.  Python indexing starts at 0.

```
no_bin_ele(1)     # 1st element of the matlab matrix
no_bin_ele[0]     # 1st element of the array

n1(1:end,1)       # matlab matrix is 2d
n1[1: ,1]         # n1 isn't 2d
n1                # should just be
```

Actually I think the last few lines should be

```
s2=int(no_bin_ele[0]*7+4)*360)
n1=m6[:s2]
j1 = np.reshape(n1, (-1, 360))    # -1 stands in for no_bin_ele[0]*7+4
```

Though this reshape may have `order` problems.  MATLAB is column-major, like `order='F'`, with the trailing dimension outermost.

I'd really like to see some sample data to verify the steps.  There are limits to what I can deduce just by reading code.  But I'm not interesting in handling data that's 12218+ bytes long.

Again, an Octave sample:

```
>> n1 = 1:10;
>> reshape(n1, 5,2)
ans =

    1    6
    2    7
    3    8
    4    9
    5   10
```

and numpy:

```
In [481]: n1 = np.arange(1,11)                                                  
In [482]: np.reshape(n1, (5,2))                                                 
Out[482]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
In [483]: np.reshape(n1, (5,2),order='F')                                       
Out[483]: 
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
In [484]: np.reshape(n1, (2,5))                                                 
Out[484]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

===

`m5` is the file, read as `uint8`, unsigned bytes.

`m6` is a large trailing part, which we want to reshape into (n,360) matrix (or its transpose).

`no_bin_ele` is an earlier part that apparently is 2 byte numbers, and we use the first of those to select a slice of `m6` for that reshaping.

It might be easier to do this translation if we had a text description of this file's format.  Deducing the matlab behaviour without a sample, or description, is likely to be buggy.

Comment: `j1 = np.reshape(n1, (-1, 360))    # -1 stands in for no_bin_ele[0]*7+4`  

can you please explain to me the logic behind using **-1**.  @hpaulj

Comment: `j1 = np.reshape(n1, (-1, 360))`
And here, why **n1** has no parameters? @hpaulj

Comment: By following the above solution, no errors are occurring. Thanks @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

Please, try enclosing the second and the third argument in parentheses compressing it into 1:

```
j1 = np.reshape(n1[1: ,1], (no_bin_ele[1]*7+4, 360*1))
```

as shown here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Python equivalent code. I don't have access to 'aa.dwr', so please check if the j1 coming from matlab is equal to j1 coming from code below.

```py
import numpy as np
with open('aa.dwr', 'rb') as fp:
    m5 = np.fromstring(fp.read(), dtype='uint8')
    m5 = m5.astype(float)
    m5 = m5.tolist()
    m6 = m5[12513:]
    no_bin_ele = m5[12038:12219:2]+256*m5[12039:12219:2]
    s1 = len(m6)
    s2=((no_bin_ele[0]*7+4)*360)*1
    s2 =int(s2)
    n1=m6[:s2+1]
    j1 = np.reshape(n1[0: ,0], (no_bin_ele[0]*7+4, 360*1))
```

Comment: Will you, please, supply a link to a sample '.dwr' file? I will like to replicate it here and see if it can be fixed.

Comment: I cant find the link and i am so sorry, i am not allowed to give the data.

Comment: can you tell m5.shape?

Comment: print(m5.shape)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: please add print statement after 4th line and not after 5th line  the first line is import statement

Comment: ppp.py:4: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  m5 = np.fromstring(fp.read(), dtype='uint8')
(40347260,)

Answer (score 0):

This reproduces your error message:

```
In [432]: [1,2,3][1:,1]                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-432-1613afcfe2a2> in <module>
----> 1 [1,2,3][1:,1]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

That means that in

```
j1 = np.reshape(n1[1: ,1], no_bin_ele[1]*7+4, 360*1)
```

`n1` is a list, where as you are using `numpy` array style index.

Errors when trying `n1.shape` have the same issue - a list doesn't have a `shape`.

`n1` derives from `m6` which comes from `m5` which comes from a `tolist()` method!

In MATLAB everything is a MATRIX (except for cells and struct).  In Python lists are the closest, but with the addition of `numpy`, you get arrays that are more like MATLAB - except their number of dimensions can be 0,1,2, etc.  When debugging pay attention to variable's `type`, and if array, `shape` and `dtype`.

Comment: okay, so list doesn't have shape!  Any suggestions on what should I do next? @hpaulj

Comment: Should I go for array instead of list? if so, how?

Comment: i = np.asarray(n1)
j1=np.reshape(i[0:,0],int((no_bin_ele[0]*7+4,360*1)))
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Why did you use `m5=m5.tolist()`?

Comment: if I won't use list then no_bin_ele = m5[12038:12219:2]+256*m5[12039:12219:2] throw me an error saying ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (91,) (90,)

Comment: but did changing `m5` to a list produce the right result?  `+` and `*` do entirely different things with lists.  To translate code like this you have test each step, in both languages.  Stop guessing!